# Why is JAVA_Home causing some issue with Ionic?

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

Before you mark this question duplicate , please consider my request.

I am able to build and run ionic apps on c9 workspace. Works perfectly. But somehow my laptop is causing me JAVA_HOME problem

jdk has been installed , JAVA_Home points to C:\Progra~1\JAVA\jdk1.7.0.79

but still I cannot `ionic run android` . Please help me

PS I tried uninstalling and reinstalling JDK. I am on windows 10 OS

[image]

Comment: That should be `JAVA_HOME`, not `JAVA_Home`.

Comment: Do you have the path set to your %JAVA_HOME%/bin ?

Comment: It is JAVA_HOME and path is not set to bin :(

Answer (score 0):

Right before you run `ionic run android`, run this first:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version
```

If you get an error, out if the output is not the Java version you expected, then `JAVA_HOME` is not set correctly. While debugging, you can set it in the shell, using:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\path\to
```

And then repeat the previous command to test if you got the syntax, spelling, and quoting right.

**Update**

From your error message, it looks like ionic is looking for the Java executable on the path, not using Java home. So as it to path, for example:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\path\to
set PATH=℅JAVA_HOME℅\bin;℅PATH%
ionic run android
```

Comment: when I run %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java - version . I get the right version without error. But still ionic is not able to pickit up @janos

Comment: Please include in your post the output of the version command, and the error output of ionic

Comment: java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)  Java Hostspot (TM)  64-bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23,mixed mode)  ........ this is output of java version ... And i have attached the updated snapshot of ionic error to the question .. Also please note that I have created my own folder called java in C: directly to avoid spaces in Program Files. so JAVA_HOME now is C:/java and path is %JAVA_HOME%\bin